# Creating a XBRL document in Java?

Tags: java, xbrl

I just started with XBRL.
What Java lib(s) do you use for creating XBRL documents?

I find it hard to find "opensource" java libs for XBRL creation/manipulation.

Comment: http://www.xbrlapi.org and http://www.xbrlwiki.info/index.php?title=Open_Source_and_XBRL. What are you looking for that you're not finding?

Comment: @David: thanks, didn't find he opensource overview in de wiki however. Did find the xbrlapi, but has short commings in creating xbrl doc's as far as I am aware of till now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use JAXB, and seem to work fine. I create the java code with jaxb ref implementation and use it through the factories...

Answer (score 0):

@edbras: Check out Arelle.org. It's not Java, but it's free and it is python, and some java, which should be close enough. There are other commercial options if you are interested.

regards,

Per Solli